# What's different between TaskStackBuilder.addParentStack() and TaskStackBuilder.addNextIntent()?

Tags: android, notifications, back-stack, android-8.0-oreo

I try to test Notification Channel in Android O by following the android tutorial. When I get into the step showing notification I saw they use `TaskStackBuilder` and I wondering that what is `addParentStack()` doing?.
Because when I removed this line of code it still works fine.

I try to test it by adding more parent like this:

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    Intent openMainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Intent openMain2Intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    Intent openMain3Intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(Main2Activity.class);

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openMain3Intent);
    return stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

as above code, I add more than one parent and expect that when I press back from `Main3Activity` it should go to `Main2Activity` and `MainActivity` respectively but the result is it returns to home screen immediately.

I changed it by removing `addParentStack()` and added more `addNextIntent()` like this:

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent() {
    Intent openMainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    Intent openMain2Intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    Intent openMain3Intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openMainIntent);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openMain2Intent);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(openMain3Intent);
    return stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

everything is working fine as I expected, it opened `Main3Activity` and went to `Main2Activity` and `MainActivity` when I pressed back button.

I found some people said that I need to add `android:parentActivityName` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` when I use `addParentStack()`, I did it but the result was same, nothing happened.

So, I would appreciate if someone can tell me that:

- What does the `addParentStack()` do?
- What is different between `addParentStack()` and `addNextIntent()`?
- Do we need to use `addParentStack()`?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3):

so,i found this on the official documents

**1.addParentStack()**

it adds the back stack(means if you will press the back button it will take you to the activity you will give to this method)

**2.Diff between addParentStack() and addNextIntent()**

the basic difference is the addnextIntent() will add the intent to the top of stack

**3.do we need the addParentStack()?**

not if you don't want to go to the parent activity after pressing back button or you have declared in the manifest file

**the code below is from the official document, it will help you understanding this**

```
int id = 1;
...
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
 // Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
 ...
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
 builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
 NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
 (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Comment: Thank for answer. Did you see the result of my first example? I expect it go back to parents that I added but it not. Or I miss understand something?

Comment: i have not tried your code i will try it and then will tell you

Comment: using addParentStack() more than one time will not work because we can have only one parent to any activity,and your problem is solved with addNextIntent() because in this case you are adding intents to the backstack so that when you press the back button it will take you to the next intent present in the backstack

Comment: i hope you get it?

Comment: thank for finding answers. I tried to have only one `addParentStack(MainActivity.class)` in my example code and have only one `addNextIntent(openMain2Intent)` for `addNextIntent` but the result that I got wasn't as my expectation. I expected that I click back button it should go to `MainActivity` (because it is a parent of `Main2Activity` that I set) but it exited from the app. Did I miss (or misunderstand) anything?

Comment: Just uninstall your app and install it again ,if problem remains the same tell me again @Watcharin.s

Comment: And one more thing ,you have to add the parent in manifest also

Comment: Hi  Dheeraj Joshi, I tried with the ways you suggest (re-install and add parent for `Main2Activity` as `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` ) but it not work.

Comment: Have you added the parent activity in manifest file?@Watcharin.s

Comment: as I said, "I add parent for Main2Activity as android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity""  in manifest.

Comment: Then you have to change your addParentStack(MainActivity.class) to addParentStack(Main2Activity.class) it will work because you have to addParentStack for Main2Activity(it will start when you click on notification) ,i tried and it works @Watcharin.s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157239/discussion-between-dheeraj-joshi-and-watcharin-s).